# Nest XML data into collection child

Tags: c#, xml, json

I'm coding in C#. I have an XMLDocument object that needs to be converted to a JSON object (I'm currently using the Newtonsoft). The XML looks something like

```
<Form attribute1="value1">
<BusinessName>BusinessName</BusinessName>
<AccountName>Account</AccountName>
</Form>
```

Without any manipulation of the XML->JSON conversion I get a JSON string like:

```
"@attribute1" : "value1",
"BusinessName" : "Business",
"AccountName" : "AccountName"
```

But what I actually need to to have that XML data in a JSON collection. So it looks something like this:

```
"@attribute1" : "value1",
"CollectionFieldName" : {
  "BusinessName" : "Business",
  "AccountName" : "AccountName"
}
```

There will only be one item in the collection. Would it be best to modify the XMLDocument then just do a plain JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode. Or should I convert the original XMLDocument then manipulate the resulting JSON string>

The current code looks something like:

```
XmlDocument serializedFormXML = new XmlDocument();
serializedFormXML.LoadXml(serializedForm); 
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(serializedFormXML, Formatting.None, true);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. (I'd personally recommend using LINQ to XML - XDocument and friends - instead of XmlDocument, too.)

Comment: I updated the question,not sure how to format the json,xml and c# into code snippets. I indented all of them four spaces.

Comment: @user1562497 Each of the 2 ways will do, but if you have control over the XML structure, why not simply change the XML in the first place? Btw, your formatting was close, only missed a single newline for each code-block

Comment: Thanks, I don't have control over the original xml structure, it's normalized data that I'm reading into the XMLDocument. So manipulating the xml would all be in memory. A description of how I would achieve either of these solutions would be awesome.